# What is expected comparison between AlphaRef and AlphaValue in D3D9?

Tags: direct3d9

The AlphaRef is set with D3DRS_ALPHAREF, which is an integer ranging from 0x00000000 to 0x000000FF. However, AlphaValue computed by shader is a float value in range [0.0, 1.0]. So what is the expected comaparison of the two value, since them have different representing precision? Does the float AlphaValue need to do extra rounding operation?

Answer (score 1):

In Direct3D 9 shaders, all input data is converted to floating-point and then converted as needed on output.

> `D3DRS_ALPHAREF` does not exist in modern DirectX 10 or later. For an example of a shader implementation of [Alph Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/alpha-testing-state). see [AlphaTestEffect.fx](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/main/Src/Shaders/AlphaTestEffect.fx) which was adapted from the original *XNA Game Studio 4* implementation.